# What is the best practices to handle multiple form operation under same action in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing, razor-2

I have the following scenario in my ASP.NET MVC4 project using Razor Engine:

- I have a *view* with at least 4 different forms.
- I would like to handle all form POST under same *action mapping*.

Actually, the 4 forms post to different Route Mapping, as follow:

```
POST: /User/FilterRolesInUse/15
POST: /User/RemoveRoles/15
POST: /User/FilterRolesNotInUse/15
POST: /User/AddRoles/15
```

I would like to know if is it possible to handle all 4 form under the *same* Route Mapping, something where all form post to `/User/Roles/15` and then the controller can distinguish which form was submitted. The concept is something like:

```
class UserController : Controller {

  //
  // POST: /User/Roles/
  public ActionResult Roles(int? id, object form) {
    return DelegateToFormLogic(id, form);
  }

}
```

I just want to know if is it possible because I really want to keep URL *consistent*.

Any *advice* or *suggestion* are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any advantage to having a single action that performs multiple functions. In fact it will be confusing to anyone that has to support the code. I would get away from submitting forms and use Ajax methods in your web client (using JQuery ajax) to get the data you need for this view and for update/insert/delete actions. This way you do not have to post back the whole page to perform actions that will probably take place on just portions of the view which will result in a better performing page and a better user experience. Change your controller to a ASP.NET Web API controller and make those methods a REST API that uses consistent URL naming convention and use HTTP verbs to indicate the type of action being performed.  You will end up 3 methods that serve  the 4 you have now and it could look something like this (they correspond to the same order listed in the question).

```
GET: /api/Role/15?InUse=True
DELETE: /api/Role/15
GET: /api/Role/15?InUse=False
POST: /api/Role
```

Your controller would look like this.

```
class RoleController : ApiController {

  public List<Role> Get(int id, boolean InUse) { ... }
  public void Delete(int id) { ... }
  public void Post(List<Role> roles) { ... }
}
```

This maintains a clear separation of concerns while also keeping a consistent and understandable URL convention.

Comment: Indeed! The separation of concerns is a must have, and your suggestion about using Web API is definitively the way to handle this scenario. Thanks @kevin-junghans!